# Why does this function works?

Tags: r, recursion, fibonacci, memoization

with this function you can calculate the fibonacci sequence with a recursive function, but i am not sure why this works, i marked at which position i struggled, can someone explain me this code?

```
fib <- function(n){
  if (n == 0) return(0) 
  if (n == 1) return(1)
  seq <- integer(n)  # at this point i didnt understand much at all
  seq[1:2] <- 1
  calc <- function(n) { 
    if (seq[n] != 0) return(seq[n])
    seq[n] <<- calc(n-1) + calc(n-2)
    seq[n]
  }
  calc(n)
}
```

Comment: My suggestion to you would be to set a value of `n` and then run the lines of code in the function line-by-line so you can get a sense of what each command is doing. This will help you decipher what is going on, as opposed to just running the whole function at once.

Comment: To answer your *specific* question, `integer(n)` creates an integer vector of length `n` full of zeros.

Comment: what about the following code? for example why is it necessary to include "if (seq[n] != 0) return(seq[n])"?

Comment: I wanted to make the recursive function faster by saving the previous results, I didnt know that this would be bad...

Comment: Now that I understand it I think this isn't a bad question, but it was very hard to understand the goal of the code. If you had laid out things in more detail (e.g. "here is a basic recursive implementation of Fibonacci in R ... now I want to speed things up by saving previous versions ..."). But just presenting code and saying "I don't understand why this works" doesn't tend to be very well received (as you are seeing). (If you don't understand the code, where did it come from in the first place ...?)

Comment: If you *edit* your question to make it clearer what you're asking about I will happily upvote it ...

Answer (score 2):

In the course of the recursive function evaluation, `fib()` ends up getting called many times with the same `n`. One way to make this computation faster is to use **memoization**, which saves a record of values for which the function has previously been called, and the return values. Using @AnoushArivanR's `fib` function:

```r
system.time(fib(30))
##    user  system elapsed 
##   3.987   0.000   3.987 
library(memoise)
fib <- memoise(fib)
system.time(fib(30))
##    user  system elapsed 
##   0.004   0.000   0.004
```

In fact, now that I look at your code above, I believe it's doing exactly this — but it's definitely hard to understand! (Your question might have been better received if you explained that this was what you're trying to do ...)

Comment: Thank you dear Mr. Bolker for the edits on my post. I have to mention that this code is taken from Dr. Roger Peng's Mastering Software Development in R.

Comment: yes, Im sorry, next time I will explain it better

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't see it at first. I think that the function isn't doing something similar to memoization, it is doing it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**

This implementation of `fib` function has been cited from Mastering Software Development in R by Dr. Roger D. Peng who taught me so much and I am forever grateful to him.

As mentioned above this code is poorly written and has been unnecessarily complicated. Here is a more simpler version. We first check that the `n` value is not less than `0`, then as the first two elements of the sequence are necessary for the series calculation to start (each element being the sum of two previous elements in the series) we set them as `0` and `1` for `n == 1` and `n == 2` respectively. Then we use recursion which is a technique that a function calls itself from its body creating a series of repetitive computations until the maximum number of `n` is reached. So for example for `n == 3` the function calls it self by calling `fib(1)` and `fib(2)` both of which have already been set and so on. Then for `fib(4)` the function calls both `fib(3)` and `fib(2)`. `fib(2)` is already set and `fib(3)` will be calculated by summing `fib(2)` and `fib(1)` and ...
I hope this explanation has helped you get your mind around the idea.

```
fib <- function(n){
  stopifnot(n > 0)
  if(n == 1) {
    return(0)
  } else if(n == 2) {
    return(1)
  } else {
    fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
  }
}

fib(7)
8
```

But as some of the calculations are computed more than once for example both `fib(6)` and `fib(5)` calculate `fib(4)` the execution of the function gets slower. For the sake of optimization your code has saved every `fib(n)` output into and empty vector called `seq` so before any computation takes place it checks whether the value for `seq[n]` has already been computed or not. If so, it will be used and if not it will be computed again. This technique is called memoization and whenver a new `seq[n]` is calculated it will be the `n`th element of the `seq` vector and for this purpose we make use of `<<-` called complex assignment operator as we are modifying an object in the parent environment of the function.

Comment: but this would be to slow for example fib(45), is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: I will explain why this would be slow.

Comment: Recursion is slower than direct computation in languages like R that don't implement [tail recursion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6230/what-is-tail-recursion). Do you **need** it to be fast?

Comment: Can you explain why (and why you're implementing it if recursively, if so?) It's not impossible to make this fast (I will show how in an answer), but it is definitely doing things the hard way. Did someone say "I need you to write a fast Fibonacci calculator, **and** I need you to implement it in R, **and** it needs to implemented as a recursive function" ... ?

Comment: I just want to  practice how to make a recursive function faster, I know it is not a great Idea, but I just want to practice, so I need it

Comment: @dddd After you read the answers here you can refer to this to find out more:
https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/RProgDA/functional-programming.html